# Laravel accessing an extra field in a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working a many-many relationship with an extra field in the pivot table.  I have a list of categories that I want to associate with a blueprint and include an extra field.
On the edit page for this blueprint, I want to show all of the categories and fill in the value of the extra field if it exists.  Then the user can edit any of these category extra values and save back to the pivot table.

In edit.blade.php I'm iterating over the categories to create labels and inputs for each one.  However, I'm stuck at how to populate the pre-existing value for each category if it doesn't exist in the pivot table.

```
@foreach ($categories as $id=>$category) 
   <label for="{{$id}}">{{$category}}</label>
   <input type="number" name="{{$id}}" id="{{$id}}" 
          value="{{ old($id, $blueprint->categories[$id]->pivot->questions or '') }}" />                       
@endforeach
```

A dump of my blueprint and associated categories array looks like:

```
blueprint
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Living things",
  "categories": [
                    {
                    "id": 1,
                    "category": "plants",
                    "pivot": {
                        "blueprint_id": 1,
                        "category_id": 1,
                        "questions": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                    "id": 3,
                    "category": "animals",
                    "pivot": {
                        "blueprint_id": 1,
                        "category_id": 3,
                        "questions": 3
                        }
                    }
                ]
}
```

Category 2 might be 'insects', but I haven't associated this with 'Living things' yet.
The problem is that when the loop gets to category 2, it can't find that key in the array and fails with an undefined key error.

Thanks for any help!
Cyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first check the existence of the relationship between blueprint and category, then get your extra field. Refer to [laravel querying relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
@foreach ($categories as $id=>$category) 
    <label for="{{$id}}">{{$category}}</label>

    @if($blueprint->has('categories') && $blueprint->categories->has($id) && $blueprint->categories[$id]->pivot->questions)
        <input type="number" name="{{$id}}" id="{{$id}}" 
              value="{{ old($id, $blueprint->categories[$id]->pivot->questions or 
    @else
        <input type="number" name="{{$id}}" id="{{$id}}" 
              value="{{ old($id) }}" />
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm still getting the undefined key error when it hits an $id that doesn't exist after the && in: @if($blueprint->has('categories') && $blueprint->categories[$id]->pivot->questions)

Comment: @cyles I've updated the answer. and I've added `&& $blueprint->categories->has($id)`

Comment: Thanks for that. I understand better about where the has() goes.  However, the value I'm getting in the input field is related to the sequence in the category array rather than the 'id' field.  For example above 'plants' is element 0 and 'animals' is element 1 in that array.  How do I find the element with a value associated with the 'id' key?

Comment: Another solution I was trying in the controller was: `@foreach ($blueprint->categories as $subarray)
    @if (isset($subarray['id']) && $subarray['id'] == $id)
         $questions = $subarray->pivot->questions;
    @endif
@endforeach`  Which gave me the right value, but how do I put this in blade?